# multivariate convergence in distribution for Skorohod topology

Tags: probability-theory, weak-convergence

If $X_n$ is a $R^d$-valued sequence of stochastic processes and $X$ is a $R^d$-valued the limiting process, all having Cadlag paths. I know what it means by
$X_n \Rightarrow X$,
i.e. $X_n$ converges weakly to $X$ in Skorohod topology. However, if $Y$ is another a $R^m$-valued stochastic process, how should I understand the convergence
$(Y,X_n) \Rightarrow (Y,X)$?

By definition, it should mean that the joint law of $(Y,X_n)$ weakly converges
to the joint law $(Y,X)$ in the space $\mathbb{D}^{m\times d }$. But one should note that it's well known that $\mathbb{D}^m \times \mathbb{D}^d$ is not topologically the same as $\mathbb{D}^{m\times d }$.